# Handling form post values and array manipulation

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, arraylist

I have `$_POST` values like this.

The below value is coming from a form.

What I would like to do is.

1. Author Code 1 and Author Code 3 has a new flag called `[chkName_1] => 1`
   So this value alone should get inserted into the database
2. Author Code 2 does not have the flag and that should be ignored.

   ```
   [author_code_1] => 1
   [author_name_1] => Author 1
   [chkName_1] => 1
   [author_code_2] => 2
   [author_name_2] => Author 2
   [author_code_3] => 3
   [author_name_3] => Author 3
   [chkName_3] => 1
   ```

The above array should run in a loop and the insert statement should look something like this.

```
insert Into author_log (`author_code`,`author_name`) values (1,'Author 1');     
insert Into author_log (`author_code`,`author_name`) values (3,'Author 3');
```

In other words, check the flag values and if it is set to 1 then insert into db.

Thanks, 
Kimz 
PS: I don't even have any idea of handling this and running a forloop.

Comment: This is a bit like the old joke, _How do I get to the town Hall. Well I would not start from here_. That array is not helping you process the information in it. So I would change the HTML for the <input> fields to name them in a more useful way. But you dont show your <form> html. Add that to your question, and you will get a much better solution.

Comment: not a joke. i need some help desperately

Comment: I was not suggesting it was. Like I say, post your html for the <form> and I will suggest a better solution

Comment: what i would do is to make things easier, make a form grouping name array so that it would enable me to insert values without complication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $authors = array(
        'author_code_1' => 1,
        'author_name_1' => 'author1',
        'chkName_1' => 1,
        'author_code_2' => 2,
        'author_name_2' => 'author2',
        'author_code_3' => 3,
        'author_name_3' => 'author3',
        'chkName_3' => 1
    );

    // _ CODE STARTS HERE
    $list = array();
    foreach ($authors as $key => $entry) {
        if (strpos($key, 'author_name_') !== false) {
            $index = str_replace('author_name_', '', $key);
            $list[$index]['name'] = $entry;
        } elseif (strpos($key, 'author_code_') !== false) {
            $index = str_replace('author_code_', '', $key);
            $list[$index]['code'] = $entry;
        } else if (strpos($key, 'chkName_') !== false) {
            $index = str_replace('chkName_', '', $key);
            $list[$index]['chk'] = $entry;
        }

    }
    // ^ CODE ENDS HERE

    print_r($list);
?>
```

Use this code to transform that mess of a post request in something more operation-friendly.
Though you should really modify your form.

[**Test**](https://eval.in/173640)